# scala getClass and type erasure?

Tags: scala, types, erasure

I am a little puzzled by the getClass method when used in generic type case:

```
def a[K](key: K) = {
  println(key.getClass)
}
```

Shouldn't this always been AnyRef or Any or something? Since type K info is not available in runtime?

but `a(3)` will output `Int` , and `a("fdasf")` will output `String.`

---

Alright, this is a silly question, I get confused by the K and key's type information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While at compile time the compiler doesn't know `K`'s type, at runtime you are always passing in an object of a specific type. Every object knows what type it is. When you call `getClass`, you are calling a method on the object, so you get back its actual type.

Answer (score 1):

at run time `a(3)` the passed value to `a` is `3` and now if **compiler** checks its value's type then it ofcourse returns `Integer`

```
scala>   def a[K](key: K) = {
     |   println(key.getClass)
     |   }
a: [K](key: K)Unit

scala> a(3)
class java.lang.Integer

scala> a("34")
class java.lang.String

scala> a(34.34)
class java.lang.Double
```

Comment: alright, you are right, seems I get confused with the type K's usage. K do not carry detail type information, while key does?